# Exact sampling distribution of sample proportion

Tags: distributions, sampling, binomial-distribution

Let $\hat{p}=\frac{\sum_i^nX_i}{n}$. I know that $\sum_i^nX_i \sim Binomial(n,p)$, but what about $\hat{p}$? (I am asking about its exact distribution, not the normal approximation).

If not possible, can we at least "write" the probability mass function of $\hat{p}$?

Comment: Since the pmf of $n\hat p$ is that of the Binomial distribution, there's not really anything to do, since $\Pr(\hat p = k) = \Pr(n\hat p = nk).$

Comment: I understand, thank you. But would be correct (based on that observation) to say that then the distribution is binomial too?

Comment: Not quite, because Binomial distributions are probability distributions on the integers while this is a distribution on the integral multiples of $1/n.$  One might call it a multiple of a Binomial.  The relationship between them is so clear and simple that there's little point in extending the definition of the Binomial distribution to include a scale parameter.

Comment: I see. But then how to use $\Pr(n\hat p = nk)$? We have that $n\hat{p}$ is binomial with parameters $n$ and $p$, but you cannot write down $\Pr(n\hat p = nk)$ since $nk > n$.

Comment: The values of $k$ are limited to the set $\{0,1/n, 2/n, \ldots, n/n\},$ whence $0 \le nk \le n.$